# Can anyone show me step by step how to determine the following limit?

Tags: limits

Can anyone show me step by step how to determine the following limit?

$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\sin \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{x}\right)$

Comment: Hint: if only there was a $\sin(x)$ on the bottom...

Answer (score 3):

since 
$$
|\sin(\cdot)|\le 1
$$
then using the above inequality you can show that:
$$
0\le\left|\frac{\sin \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{x}\right|\le\frac{1}{|x|} \to 0 \,\,\,{\rm{for}}\,\,\,x\to\infty
$$
by the squeeze theorem the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$| \sin(\sin(x))| \le 1$  for all $x$. Hence the limit in question is $=0$